# Is it possible to redirect stdout twice with dup2?

Tags: c, file-descriptor, dup2

I have a problem when I used `dup2` direct `stdout` first to a temporal file, and after to a common file. This is a portion my code:

```
FILE* fdArch=fopen("file.txt","w");

    char nameBuff[100];

    memset(nameBuff,0,sizeof(nameBuff));

    strncpy(nameBuff,"/tmp/myTmpFile-XXXXXX",sizeof("/tmp/myTmpFile-XXXXXX"));

    int fdNewFile=mkstemp(nameBuff);

    if(fdNewFile==-1){
        perror("error creating temporal file");
    }

    dup2(fdNewFile,STDOUT_FILENO);

    read(fd[0], readbuffer, sizeof(readbuffer));

    char *argv[]={ "/home/user/workspace/CProgram/Debug/program", readbuffer, NULL};

    execv(argv[0],argv);

    close(fdNewFile);

    dup2(fileno(fdArch),STDOUT_FILENO);

    char *argv1[]={"/usr/bin/sort",nameBuff, NULL};

    execv(argv1[0],argv1);

    fclose(fdArch);

    unlink(nameBuff);
```

I run an external program called program and the out is redirected with `dup2` to a temporal file, well this works fine, but after when I redirect with `dup2` the `stdout` to `fdArch` and run sort over the temporal file, the out is not redirected to `fdArch`.

Is there an error of concept or something is missing?

Comment: You do know that `execv()` doesn't return unless there's an error, right? Are you expecting the code you put after `execv()` to execute?

Comment: Yeah. You're missing a `fork` before the `execv`s.

Comment: yes, so it does not run?, before using execv I used system but I was told that it was slower

Comment: `system()` may be slower because it must setup signal handlers (POSIX requires that `system()` blocks `SIGCHLD` and ignores `SIGINT` and `SIGQUIT`), and it starts a new bash session to run the commands, whereas if you `exec()` them directly, it's faster - you don't have to wait the extra time for the new shell to parse the commands, fork and execute them. But I'd say just stick to `system()`, you probably won't see a difference.

Comment: But the code following the execv will be run? and also, the dup2 out will be redirected to fdArch?

Comment: @user4910023, no the code following the `execv()` will *not* be run, unless, of course, the `execv()` fails.  That's why you `fork()` if you want the program to continue after the `execv()`: that creates a second process, which `execv()` can then replace without disturbing the original.  In fact, it's basically what `system()` does, with a bit less frill.

Comment: I've done this with system, but now I'm bound not using it, how would you do that?

Comment: @user4910023, I described a way for you to do this with `execv()` instead of `system()` in my answer.  Feel free to add comments there if you need clarification.

Answer (score 2):

> I run an external program called program and the out is redirected with dup2 to a temporal file, well this works fine, but after when I redirect with dup2 the stdout to fdArch and run sort over the temporal file,the out is not redirected to fdArch. Is there an error of concept or something is missing?

Your usage of `dup2()` is fine, but you do have a major error: the `execv()` function does not return, except when it fails.  It, and all the other functions in its family, *replace* the program in which it is called with the one specified.  Thus, in fact you never do redirect `stdout` a second time or run `/bin/sort`.  If you want to do those things, then you should `fork()`, perform the `execv()` in the child process, and have the parent `wait()` for it to complete before continuing.

Comment: Thansk, thats what I'm gonna do.